# Why do simple informational comments get deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted a comment to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/was-pierre-teilhard-de-chardin-a-defender-of-eugenics), giving a link to a relevant and useful document.  The comment was deleted by someone, without informing me of the reason.  Why do such comments get deleted?

Note that this wasn't an "opinion" comment or in any way biased.

Answer (score 7):

The [Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) explains:

> #### When should I comment?

> You should submit a comment if you want to:

> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
>   Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

This comment fit none of those scenarios.

It was a link to a person who had an opinion on what the answer should be.

If it was intended as an answer, it should have been in an answer box. The link should ideally by "inlined" with some description of what it links to. It should have a summary. It should have some parts of it excerpted to support the claim and to protect against link rot.

If it was intended as a suggestion for an edit, it should have had some information about why the existing question was unsatisfactory and why it was relevant (or it even better, be bold: it could have been a direct edit).

At the very least, it needed some sort of signpost to tell a reader why they should click on a random link.

---

Please stop leaving comments that don't meet the criteria above. Pseudo-answers in comments are harmful. Personal opinions are off-topic. Just taking an opportunity to take a dig at a claimant is unhelpful. Posting an off-topic comment that ends up being deleted leaves everyone unhappy.

Comment: Except that that often gets a "This is not an answer" reaction.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Well if it's not good enough for an answer, why is it good enough for a comment?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Then please don't leave the comment, and save us having to delete it.

Comment: So ignore the information?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: If you want to answer, post an answer. If you want to help improve or clarify the question, post a comment (or edit the question directly). If you want to just share your opinion, or continue some discussion, post it in chat - don't derail the Q&A process which is the purpose of the site.

Comment: @Oddthinking - So why is suppressing information a policy here?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: That formulation of the situation is ungenerous. The policy is not "we should suppress information for the sake of suppressing information". The [policy is](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."